# `Ambiguous reference to member` when creating convenience init in extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is my `init`:

```
extension NSNumberFormatter {

    convenience init(digits: Int = 0) {
        self.init() //ambiguous reference to member 'NSNumberFormatter.init'

        groupingSeparator = " "
        decimalSeparator = "."
        numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
        roundingMode = .RoundHalfDown

        maximumFractionDigits = digits
        minimumFractionDigits = digits
    }
}
```

What is the reason?

The same problem is when I put `self.init()` at the end of my convenience initializer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that you have created a new `init` that can be called without any parameters since `digits` has a default value of `0`.  So now, `init()` can refer to the default initializer or your new one.  If you remove the default value for `digits`, it will then compile.